# installing unix on windows

Tags: unix

HI all,
           i wanted to learn unix and as i had browsed the internet,i just found this site http://expanzon.blogspot.com/ where it says an easy installation of unix so that you can start studying here.
i had done all the required downloads needed as mentioned in this site,but when i enter the login as admin and password given as root(as mentioned in the link),it is coming as incorrect password.
Can anyone please help me out to rectify this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance
Maddy

Comment: Not programming...

Comment: yes i wanted to learn the system calls

Comment: Maybe you want to learn system calls, but your question is in effect: *"What is the password ?"* and that's not programming related.

Comment: as mentioned in the link,the login was given as admnin and password as root.What could be done  about this?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to learn the UNIX *environment* (like shells and tools such as `grep`, `awk` `sed`, `perl` and so on), Cygwin is your best bet.

Head on over to their [home page](http://www.cygwin.com/) and download/run the latest installer.

If you want a full-blown Linux environment, just install and run your virtual machine emulator of choice (I prefer [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com) Player myself) and install an easy-to-use distro like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: what about the system calls,ipcs ,socket programming etc..

Comment: @paxdiablo...I hav this cygwin already installed,but not sure how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 5):

Download [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and create a virtual machine, then install a [linux distribution](http://www.ubuntu.com/) virtually and play with it. Don't use pre-installed virtual machines, or any suggested pre-configured solution. Do it yourself from the base.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the screen shot included in that post, the poster gets it wrong, too.

[image]

"admin" was entered as the user and presumably "root" as the password producing the same error you're getting. Then "root" was entered as the user and no password was entered and the login was successful.

Try entering "root" as the user.